# Does the Units of a Ring always form an Abelian Group?

Tags: ring-theory

I know that the units of a ring form a multiplicative group because it inherits the associativity from the ring; every element has its inverse by definition; it is closed under multiplication: indeed, if you take $x,y \in U(R)$ there exists $x',y' \in U(R)$ such that
$$
(x \cdot y) \cdot (y' \cdot x') = x \cdot (y \cdot y') \cdot x' = x \cdot x = 1 \implies x \cdot y, y' \cdot x' \in U(R);
$$
And it has the identity element since it itself is a unit ($1 \cdot 1 = 1$). The issue I'm having is to prove that it is abelian, and I suspect that it isn't always true.

Does anyone have a counter example or a proof for this statement?

Comment: What is $U(X)$?

Comment: The [general linear group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) is the group of units of the ring of matrices and is never abelian (unless $n=1$).

Comment: If the ring $R$ is commutative, then its group of units $U(R)$ is abelian.

Comment: Dietrich, I've corrected this mistake, it was supposed to be $U(R)$. That makes sense, lhf, in the context I was working, Commutative Algebra, this does hold. I just got confused because it wasn't specified that the ring was commutative. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. For example multiplication in Hamilton's [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) $\mathbb H$ is not commutative, so its group of units (which is everything except $0$) is not Abelian.

You can embed whatever group you want into the units of a ring using a construction called a [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring), and in particular you could put in any nonAbelian group that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Makes sense, but with this group ring construction you could embed a non abelian group into the units of a commutative ring? That I didn't understand.

Comment: @LeandroAbib No, I didn’t say that, and it would not work.  Any subgroup of the group of units of a commutative ring is abelian by definition of comutativity.

Comment: I just got confused with the sentence, sorry. And again thank you very much for the response!

Answer (score 4):

A counterexample is, for example, the ring $R=\text{End}(C_4\times C_2)$. The group of
units is given by the dihedral group $D_4$, which is non-abelian. We have
$$
R^{\times}=\text{Aut}(C_4\times C_2)\simeq D_4.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those $C_4$ and $C_2$ means what?

Comment: $C_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$. The "C" stands for cyclic. In $D_4$ the "D" stands for dihedral.

Comment: Dihedral group I was familiar with as well as the cyclic group of order $n$, just the notation I didn't understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a familiar counter-example is rings of matrices, say for example the ring of 2x2 real matrices $\mathrm{Mat}_2(\mathbb{R})$. The group of units is the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, formed of those matrices with non-zero determinant. This group is not abelian, as matrix multiplication in general is non-commutative even when restricted to invertible matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much!